# Inserting 'null' values into dictionary when order matters

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I have a `list` called `entries` which is composed of multiple strings.

> Each entry in `entries` has data and also **either**
>   `closeloop` **or** `txup cycle`, `txdown cycle`, `rxup cycle` and `rxdown cycle`
>   followed by times, and the date comes from somewhere else in the entry
>   (taken care of by the 'utdate' in my `dtdict`).

The order of each entry in `entries` matters, and I need to update my dictionary `d` with the dates/times after they've been converted to UTC, but for every 'closeloop' entry I need that corresponding value in the dictionary to be 'NULL'. Here's what I have:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

rawdates = []
converted_dt = []
converted_txup = []
local = pytz.timezone("Etc/GMT+4")
d = {}
dtdict = {'txup': '#regexpattern',
         'txdown': '#regexpattern',
         'rxup': '#regexpattern',
         'rxdown': '#regexpattern',
         'utdate': '#regexpattern'}

cycle_entries = [e for e in entries if 'cycle' in e]
clloop_entries = [e for e in entries if 'closeloop' in e]

txupmatches = re.findall(dtdict['txup'], str(entries))
txdownmatches = re.findall(dtdict['txdown'], str(entries))
rxupmatches = re.findall(dtdict['rxup'], str(entries))
rxdownmatches = re.findall(dtdict['rxdown'], str(entries))

for entry in cycle_entries:
    dates = datetime.strptime(re.search(dtdict['utdate'], entry).group(0), '%c')
    localdatestr = str(dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    rawdates.append(localdatestr)
for i in range(len(cycle_entries)):
    local_time = datetime.strptime(rawdates[i]+' '+txupmatches[i], '%Y-%m-%d %X')
    localized_time = local.localize(local_time)
    utc_time_str = str(localized_time.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')
    converted_txup.append(utc_time_str)
for entry in entries:
    d.update({'txup': converted_txup if re.search(dtdict['txup'], entry) else 'NULL'})
```

But this doesn't do what I want -- when I print `d['txup']` I need a list of values which includes a converted datetime string for every 'cycle' entry and the value 'NULL' for every 'closeloop' entry in the same order as each entry appears in `entries`. Anyone know how to take care of this problem?

I'm also going to have to add additional lines of code to do the same thing for 'txdown', 'rxup', and 'rxdown', so if there's a more efficient way of doing the same thing also please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using `OrderedDict` when you define `d`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Or use python 3.6, which orders dicts by default.

Comment: Without Example Data of `entries` I'm not able to do a Testrun, also show the Output you get **and** the Output you want. [Edit] your Question accordingly.

Comment: @MikeTheReader Oh hey, that's interesting. Thanks!